# Four Coins and Pairwise Independent but not mutual

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, independence

I understand how we can have three coin tosses (or three events if you prefer) such that all three tosses are pairwise independent, but not mutually independent. One trivial example of this would be to just have the third coin be the xor of the first two coins. My question is whether it's possible to have four or more coin tosses such that any two coin tosses are pairwise independent, but any three coin tosses are not independent. If this is not possible, what would a proof be like showing that it isn't?

Comment: "*have the third coin be the xor of the first two coins*"  That doesn't sound like a coin at that point at all...  a random event sure, but not a coin.

Comment: Yeah I mean I just use coins to say that the random variable can only be 0 or 1. Like the first two coins are random, and then magically the third coin assumes the value of their xor.

Answer (score 1):

The question is as I interpret it to give an example of a collection of four or more events such that they are all pairwise independent but are not independent when taken three or more at a time.

To help build such an example, let us try to work with easy to calculate numbers and simple distributions like a uniform distribution.  Events with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{1}{4}$ in particular are helpful.  After some attempts I did not come up with a good example using $\frac{1}{2}$'s but $\frac{1}{4}$'s wound up working well.  In order to have two independent events each with probability $\frac{1}{4}$ we would need their intersection to have probability $\frac{1}{16}$.  If three were collectively independent it would have needed a probability of $\frac{1}{64}$.  So long as we are working with a uniform distribution and have less than $64$ outcomes then it will clearly be impossible using $\frac{1}{4}$ probability events for three or more to be events to be mutually independent.  Further, if we were to work with a size $16$ sample space, all we would need for two events to be pairwise independent would be to have them intersect at a single element.  With that, we build our example:

---

Consider the sample space $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16\}$ and the uniform probability distribution over this space.

Consider the events: $\{1,2,3,4\},\{1,5,6,7\},\{1,8,9,10\},\{1,11,12,13\}$.  (*we can even include the event $\{1,14,15,16\}$ here as a happy coincidence*)

Each of these events can be trivially seen to have probability $\dfrac{4}{16} = \dfrac{1}{4}$

Each intersection of two events can be seen to have intersection $\{1\}$ and so probability $\dfrac{1}{16}=\dfrac{1}{4}\times\dfrac{1}{4}$ and so are pairwise independent.

Each intersection of three or more events can also be seen to have intersection $\{1\}$ and so also probability $\dfrac{1}{16}$ which is not going to be equal to $\dfrac{1}{4}\times\dfrac{1}{4}\times\dfrac{1}{4}$ or less.

---

This is effectively the same example as the one you gave: the uniform distribution over $\{1,2,3,4\}$ with events $\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\}$ using probability $\frac{1}{2}$ events.  This same idea can also be used to construct larger examples by induction... using $2^k+1$ events of probability $\frac{1}{2^k}$ in a uniform sample space of size $4^k$ who all share a single element, showing that you can have an arbitrarily large number of events who are pairwise independent but who have no triple or larger which is mutually independent.

Comment: I see how this works with sets, but how do we interpret a set in terms of coin flips? Like if we have the set {1,2} is that just coins 1 and 2 coming up heads?

Comment: @eliyablon If you insist, you could instead of $\{1,2,3,4,5,\dots,15,16\}$ relabel this as $\{HHHH,HHHT,HHTH,HHTT,HTHH,HTHT,\dots,TTTT\}$, so the set $\{1,2\}$ in the example above after relabeling is $\{HHHH,HHHT\}$ and corresponds to the event "The first three coins all show heads"

Comment: @eliyablon the way I chose to define the sets does not work well in terms of the metaphor of flipping coins, but to be fair neither did your example with the "xor of the other two coins 'coin'".  Regardless, they do work well as events in a simple to explain probability space.

Comment: Rather than thinking of the uniform distribution over $\{1,2,\dots,16\}$ as several coin flips, it is far easier to visualize as the rolling of a sixteen-sided die.  The event $\{1,2\}$ is very simply the event "*a 1 or a 2 showed up on the result of the rolling of the die*"